# Change the structure of an object in JS

Tags: javascript, object

```
const a = {
  0: { country: "france", date:"sfzef"},
  1: { country: "italie", date:"ttttt"},
  2: { country: "belgique", date:"zzzee"}
}

let obj = {}
for (const property in a) {
  obj = {...obj, `${a[property].country}: ${a[property]}`}
}
```

I would like to have :

```
obj = {
  france: { country: "france", date:"sfzef"},
  italie: { country: "italie", date:"ttttt"},
  belgique: { country: "belgique", date:"zzzee"}
}
```

I've been trying for 4 hours, thanks in advance to the one who will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you're creating a string, when you need to be doing a key/value pair of the object. A computed key can be done with square brackets around the key:

```js
const a = {
  0: { country: "france", date:"sfzef"},
  1: { country: "italie", date:"ttttt"},
  2: { country: "belgique", date:"zzzee"}
}

let obj = {}
for (const property in a) {
  obj = {...obj, [a[property].country]: a[property]}
}

console.log(obj);
```

If you want to avoid copying the object each time, you can do this:

```
let obj = {}
for (const property in a) {
  obj[a[property].country] = a[property]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: use a `reducer` on the entries of the `Object` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

```js
const a = {
  0: { country: "france", date:"sfzef"},
  1: { country: "italie", date:"ttttt"},
  2: { country: "belgique", date:"zzzee"}
};
const b = Object.entries(a)
  .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [value.country]: value}), {} );

console.log(b);
```